# Pod needs the same key label to work with two different network policies

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod, kubernetes-networkpolicy

I have two network policies (one with pod selector app=db and the other with app=proxy) and I have one pod to apply both network policies, the pod config doesn't allow to have 2 different labels with the same key app.

How can I do it in this case without modifying any network policies?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the pod/label/app selector is the only selector in each policy then it's not possible. The net policy probably needs a   `matchExpressions` selector then a new label.

Ingress and Egress rules can supply an array of `podSelector`s for the network targets, or similar `matchExpressions`

```
spec:
  podSelector:
    matchExpressions:
      - key: role
        operator: In
        values: [ "db-proxy", "db" ]
```

Comment: Yaml does not "support" identical keys for the objects. Depending on the parser only one of those would be used (or the parser would throw an error)

Comment: Yep, my bad. It's the ingress and egress rules that support an multiple podSelectors via array.